# Pandas GroupBy Consecutive with Where Condition

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to "combine" consecutive rows of like data where certain conditions match, and everything I've tried is throwing errors or putting the data together in an unexpected way.

Data:

```
       open    high     low   close     volume       datetime
0    257.31  259.04  255.63  257.86  335889185  1510552800000
1    258.14  260.48  257.86  260.36  190142219  1511157600000
2    260.41  266.05  260.00  264.46  521044032  1511762400000
3    266.31  266.80  262.71  265.51  401716112  1512367200000
4    265.58  267.56  265.39  266.51  516455674  1512972000000
..      ...     ...     ...     ...        ...            ...
151  336.06  347.35  334.38  346.85  297612670  1601874000000
152  349.59  354.02  343.13  347.29  361462322  1602478800000
153  348.65  349.33  340.65  345.78  296595696  1603083600000
154  342.13  342.98  322.60  326.54  495607791  1603688400000
155  330.20  352.19  327.24  350.16  463334913  1604296800000
```

I want to combine consecutive rows that are `open > close` and `close > open`, so that I can have one large candle (this is stock data) for consecutive of the same candles.

Initially I started with making a column to signify which type of row it is (probably not required and the comparison can be done in a one-liner during the row merges?):

```
def green_or_red(self, row):
        if row['open'] > row['close']:
            val = 'R'
        elif row['open'] < row['close']:
            val = 'G'
        else:
            val = 'N'
        return val
df['candle_is'] = df.apply(green_or_red, axis=1)
```

Which assigns it correctly, however the merging of consecutive rows is where I have an issue:

```
# merge the consecutive same types of candles
g = df['candle_is'].ne(df['candle_is'].shift()).cumsum()
dfn = df.groupby(['candle_is', g], sort=False).agg({'open': max, 'close': min, 'high': max, 'low': min, 'volume': sum})
```

produces:

```
                       open   close      high     low      volume
candle_is candle_is
G         1          260.41  257.86  266.0500  255.63  1047075436
R         2          266.31  265.51  266.8000  262.71   401716112
G         3          265.58  266.51  267.5600  265.39   516455674
R         4          268.10  266.86  268.6000  266.64   632660142
G         5          280.17  273.42  286.6285  267.40  1655227273
...                     ...     ...       ...     ...         ...
          73         342.12  326.52  350.7200  319.64  1280999271
R         74         350.35  330.65  358.7500  327.97  1257122392
G         75         336.06  328.73  347.3500  319.80  1099865805
R         76         349.59  326.54  354.0200  322.60  1153665809
G         77         330.20  350.16  352.1900  327.24   463334913
```

But I need to separate the logic between red (R) and green (G) candles so that the agg() works a bit differently because open/close values should be swapped between min/max for each type:

```
# green
df.groupby(['candle_is', g], sort=False).agg({'open': max, 'close': min, 'high': max, 'low': min, 'volume': sum})
# red
df.groupby(['candle_is', g], sort=False).agg({'open': min, 'close': max, 'high': max, 'low': min, 'volume': sum})
```

However I can't find a way to utilize `g` or `df['candle_is'] == 'G'` to target those specifically without getting a slew of errors, because once I filter the data, the size does not match. How can this be accomplished sanely? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seeking to swap your `min/max`, it might be easier noticing that `max(-array) = -min(array)`. So we can just multiply the data with `-1` and multiply back:

```
# use this instead of `apply`, which is not vectorized
candles = np.select([df['open']>df['close'], df['open']<df['close']],
                    ['R','G'], 'N')

# turn candles into series
candles =pd.Series(candles, index=df.index)

g = candles.ne(candles.shift()).cumsum()

# change sign of `red` candles so min becomes max and so on
multipliers = np.where(candles=='R', -1, 1)

# groupby as usual
# note that `'max'` is vectorize while `max` is not
ret = (df.mul(multipliers, axis='rows')
       .groupby([candles, g], sort=False)
       .agg({'open': 'max', 'close': 'min', 
             'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 
             'volume': 'sum'})
)

# multiply the red candles by `-1`
# Since we are working with MultiIndex, we slice by the level values 
ret.loc[ret.index.get_level_values(0)=='R'] *= -1
```

Output for the sample data (notice the values in the 2nd `R` group):

```
               open   close    high     low      volume
  candle_is                                            
G 1          260.41  257.86  266.05  255.63  1047075436
R 2          266.31  265.51  266.80  262.71   401716112
G 3          336.06  266.51  347.35  265.39   814068344
R 4          342.13  347.29  342.98  343.13  1153665809
G 5          330.20  350.16  352.19  327.24   463334913
```

Comment: First off, wow I can't believe you came up with something that quick. I've been trying different things for 2 days (but I'm newish to python and super-new to pandas), so thank you!
I'm getting an error "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'ne'" from the line `g = candles.ne(candles.shift()).cumsum()` in python 3.9.0 with this solution. What version did this work in?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Turn it in to series by wrapping around `pd.Series(np.select(...), index=df.index)`. See updated answer

Comment: Thank you for this! Now I've got to read about everything you did here to get an idea of what's going on and how you did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually for anyone finding this it is slightly off due to multiplying the red candles by -1, in that final high and low values for red candles are incorrect because it now chooses the "highest low" of the consecutive group.

Comment: So now it seems like we're in a similar situation that I couldn't find out before, we need to choose which rows (matching "R") to re-multiple the high and low columns by -1 again (or not do it in the first place) to get the right data

Comment: I didn’t notice you only want to swap min/max for open/close only. You can just multiply open/close columns only then.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by multiplying beforehand, then setting the other columns to the absolute value  like so:
```
df = df.mul(multipliers, axis='rows')
        df["high"] = abs(df["high"])
        df["low"] = abs(df["low"])
        ret = (df.groupby([candles, g], sort=False)
               .agg({'open': 'min', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'max', 
                     'volume': 'sum', 'datetime': 'min'})
        )
        ret.loc[ret.index.get_level_values(0)=='R'] *= -1
        ret["high"] = abs(ret["high"])
        ret["low"] = abs(ret["low"])
```